# HighCharts: How to get a specific color for value 0

Tags: highcharts

When using color stops in a heatmap, is there a way to have only values other then `0` to be effected and set fields with `0` to white. The only hack I can see is to have stops like this

```
[0, '#FFFF'], 
[0.00001, '#276C91'], 
[0.5, '#FDF6A3'], 
[1, '#B63132']
```

Answer (score 2):

Instead of stops, you can use [dataClassColor](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.dataClassColor)

> Determines how to set each data class' color if no individual color is set. The default value, tween, computes intermediate colors between minColor and maxColor. The other possible value, category, pulls colors from the global or chart specific colors array. Defaults to tween.

in combine with [dataClasses](http://api.highcharts.com/highmaps#colorAxis.dataClasses)

> An array of data classes or ranges for the choropleth map. If none given, the color axis is scalar and values are distributed as a gradient between the minimum and maximum colors.

Comment: But then I need to know at least the min ans max value of the series, or is there a way to use get it work with percentage values?

Answer (score 0):

You could extend (wrap) the `ColorAxis.toColor` function to separately handle a `value` of `0`.

For example:

```
(function (H) {
    H.wrap(H.ColorAxis.prototype, 'toColor', function (proceed, value, point) {
        if(value == 0)
            return '#FF00FF'; // My color
        else
            return proceed.apply(this, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1)); // Normal coloring
    });
}(Highcharts));
```

See [this JSFiddle demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/7mubvcss/).